# Set multiple environment variables in docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am writing a docker file in which at one specific step I am generating dynamic secret file which contains a lit of approx 20 env. variables, in below stand format:

```
export ABC=‘XXXXXXX’
export DEF=‘XXXXXXX’
export GHI=‘XXXXXXX’
export JKL=‘XXXXXXX’
```

…

I want to set all this variables values in env. variables.

I ran below command but unable to set this values in ENV

```
RUN . ./secrets/env
```

But it's unable to set all export variables as env. variables
The current option I am using now is as below:

```
ENV ABC ${xxxx}
```

Is there option available to set all secret file values as Env. values.

Comment: Don't embed secrets in docker containers, specify the secrets with `--env-file` when running the container.

Comment: I'll add that each `RUN` statement is run in a separate shell, so when you `export` something in a RUN statement, those variables are only available in that RUN statement and will be gone once the RUN statement finishes.

Comment: I can't modify the secret file